# delete the duplicate records, and keep the one that have lower id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

## I have

a users table that contains bad data. I want to loop through and delete the duplicate records in term of `email`, and keep the record that have `lower` **id**.

[image]

I want to keep only id : 1, 14, 1004, 1005, 1003, 1006, and 1007.

---

## I've tried

```
$users = DB::table('users')->where('id', DB::raw("(select min(`id`) from users)"))->get();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    if ( ???? )) { // <---- I'm not sure what to put here. 
        $user->delete();
    }
}
```

---

## I noticed

`$users = DB::table('users')->groupBy('email')->get();`

return all the records I want to keep.

Comment: sorry please ignore that. I'lll take it off, I was trying to play around with the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this

```
// get users with min id
$ids= DB::table('users')->where('id', DB::raw("(select min(`id`) from users)"))->lists('id');

// get all users
$users = \App\User::all();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    if (!in_array($user->id, $ids)) {
        $user->delete();
    }
}
```

First List all ids of the users with the minimum id ( with unique email ) , then get all users and loop through them. Delete every user who's id is not in it.

**UPDATE**

Since the upper query seems not to work here's what I would try ( not finally veryfied )

```
DB::table('users')->select('id', DB::raw('min("id") as lowest_id, email'))->groupBy('email')->lists('id')
```

Comment: this will return only one row. you need `group by email`

Comment: @Peter : I got the same result `array:1 [▼
  0 => 1
]`

Comment: @Frank : do we need to use group by ?

Comment: `$ids= DB::table('users')->where('id', DB::raw("(select min(`id`) from users)"))->groupBy('email')->lists('id');` also return `array:1 [▼ 0 => 1 ]`

Comment: It's a little tough for me to check since i currently do not have any database with me with duplicates - so here is what I'd try: DB::table('users')->select('id', DB::raw('min("id") as lowest_id, email'))->groupBy('email')->lists('id')